# The as operator to be used to perform conversions between compatible types

Tags: java

Is there any implementatin of [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) in Java?
I'm looking something as simple as following snippet of code in some shared library.

```
public static <T> T as(Class<T> clazz, Object object) {
    if (object == null)
        return null;
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()))
        return (T) object;
    return null;
}
```

Something I could use like

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Peer peer = as(Peer.class, obj);
    if (peer == null) return false;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the equivalent idiom in Java would be

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!obj instanceof Peer)
        return false;
    Peer peer = (Peer)obj;
    ...
}
```

Comment: one second faster than me :) I was just checking what "as" stands for.